# How to enter a String input instead of integer data type input using scanner

Tags: java

This is my file and I want to put String input instead of int.

import java.util.*;

public class ExceptionSample {

```
public static void main (String[]args){
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   int dividend, divisor, quotient;
   System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
   dividend = s.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter divisor: ");
   divisor = s.nextInt();

   try {
    quotient = dividend/divisor;
    System.out.println(dividend + " / " + divisor + " = " + quotient);
   }

   catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    System.out.println("Divisor cannot be 0.");
    System.out.println("Try again.");
   }

    finally  {
System.out.println("Thank you.");
}
}
```

}

And here is my revision, I tried other data type but String can't be converted.

import java.util.*;

public class ExceptionSample {

```
public static void main (String[]args){
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   int dividend, divisor, quotient;
   String dividend1, divisor1, quotient1;
   System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
   dividend1 = s.next();
   System.out.print("Enter divisor: ");
   divisor1 = s.next();

   try {

    dividend = Integer.toString(dividend1);
    divisor = Integer.toString(divisor1);
    quotient= Integer.toString(quotient1);
    quotient1 = dividend1 / divisor1;
    System.out.println("dividend1" + " / " + "divisor1" + " = " + "quotient1");
   }

   catch (ArithmeticException ex) {

    System.out.println("Divisor cannot be 0.");
    System.out.println("Try again.");
   }


    finally  {
System.out.println("Thank you.");
}
}
```

}

Comment: [`.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: Or `next()` for a single token

Comment: I'm sure it's for an assignment, but if you don't absolutely have to use scanner I'd recommend pretty much anything else.  A Swing input dialog would be really simple.  Seriously, like: div= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Dividend"); easy.

Comment: There is an error if I put next().

Comment: I even try  dividend = Integer.toString(dividend1);
     divisor = Integer.toString(divisor1);
     quotient= Integer.toString(quotient1);

Comment: It has to ask for the user input.

Comment: Of course it will throw an error, you need to change your variable data type if you use another method, because the new method will not be returning an int...

Comment: here is my revision:       import java.util.*;
public class ExceptionSample {
 public static void main (String[]args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dividend, divisor, quotient;
    String dividend1, divisor1, quotient1;
    System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
    dividend1 = s.next();
    System.out.print("Enter divisor: ");
    divisor1 = s.next();

Comment: this is the continuation:  try {
     dividend = Integer.toString(dividend1);
     divisor = Integer.toString(divisor1);
     quotient= Integer.toString(quotient1);
     
  quotient1 = dividend1 / divisor1;
  System.out.println("dividend1" + " / " + "divisor1" + " = " + "quotient1");
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
  System.out.println("Divisor cannot be 0.");
  System.out.println("Try again.");
    }
  finally  {
 System.out.println("Thank you.");
 }
 }
}

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. **Edit** the question to clarify it, and make sure your code is adequately formatted. Delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables as `String`, not `int`. Then you can use any method to read a String.

ie.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String dividend, divisor, quotient;
System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
dividend = s.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

change ".nextInt()" to ".nextLine()"

.nextInt is trying to grab an integer input, whereas .nextLine grabs a string input